# DCOS: Run a application on a specific host

Tags: mesos, dcos

Is it possible to tell to DCOS applications to run on a specific physical set of environment?

Requirement: We have a DCOS environment. Vault, Consul, DBs and custom apps are running on this DCOS environment. We need to run Vault on a separate set of physical machines. Can we approach it on same DCOS environment? Can you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of achieving this:

1. you can use [agent attributes and marathon contraints](https://dcos.io/docs/1.9/installing/faq/#q-how-to-add-mesos-attributes-to-nodes-to-use-marathon-constraints-) to distinguish between both instance types. Please note that you need to use the constraints for both applications (for application A: only run on the nodes with attribute x, and for application B: don't run on the node with attribute x).
2. use [reserved resource roles](https://dcos.io/docs/1.9/deploying-services/faq/#how-to-add-mesos-roles-for-a-node-to-dedicate-this-node-for-some-apps-). Please note, that in this case the resources can only be used for applications running in the specific role and hence cannot be used for other applications.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using conda https://conda.io/ for managing env